# Integrate Atlassian Jira with SVN

Tags: svn, jira, jira-agile, atlassian-fisheye

I use SCM Manager as SVN server for project in office. Recently, I decided to set up a issue tracker and project management, so I install Atlassian JIRA 7.1.4 and FishEye 3.8 .
To link each SVN commit with related issue, Jira can parse commit comment ( feature Smart Commit) and change the state of issues, but this feature doesn't work correctly and could not change the state of issue.

How can integrate SCM Manager with Jira ?

(Is there any other solution  to link issues with commits?)

Comment: How do you commit to SVN? with tortoise or IDE or ..?

Comment: @Razavi  Each of our developers commit to SVN by a tool, Tortoise, Intelij idea , eclipse and MPLAB.

Comment: Are you using a commit hook in SVN?

Comment: @BarnabyGolden We are not currently using it, but we use it if necessary. Is not it another way?

Comment: I was just doing some background reading and it looks like you can still get SVN hooks for JIRA 7. See this link: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/SVN-commit-and-JIRA-7-hook/qaq-p/378702

Comment: @BarnabyGolden In this way, can i change the issue's state,also?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but you should be able to. The JIRA API includes a call that allows you to change an issue's state. So you need to write a pre-commit hook script that includes the appropriate call. If I was to do this, I would first write a simple script that calls the JIRA API and changes an issue state. Then I would try and include the code from that script in a pre-commit hook script in SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the Atlassian Team, we were able to find a solution:

It appears that this functionality is available in SCM Manager. See support request for the developer to add it: [How to change issue status using SCM JIRA](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/issues/845/how-to-change-issue-status-using-scm-jira).

The developer Sebastian links to their SCM JIRA [plugin](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/jira-plugin) page and notes the auto-close section.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native solution for integrating JIRA and SVN. In order to do that, you need to use Third Party Plugins in JIRA. (You can find couple of them [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?product=jira&query=SVN))

Comment: Unfortunately, These plugins are not suitable, SVN Gateway is for cloud, Commit Policy is only limited commits and Subversion ALM also is not working correctly between tortoise and JIRA. we would like to change the issue's state by commit in SVN